# Material with feathered edge on 3D object (Cycles)

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials, transparency

I found this example online, does anyone know how to create this with Material Nodes (Cycles)? The main importance is having a feathered edge on the 3D object/material.
Thank you for any help.

[image]

Comment: Is the object 2D or 3D?

Comment: @RobinBetts sorry for not clarifying. I'm wanting to do this for a 3d object

Comment: @RobinBetts with that being said, I would like to know how to do this with a 2d object as well (but 3d is priority for me)

Comment: Are you interested in Spheres only, or a general "outline shader"?

Comment: @FrederikSteinmetz Spheres are priority but it would be good to know how to do this for other shapes too :-)

Comment: My guess is something along the lines of:
Colorramp -> Alpha socket of Principled Shder.

Comment: For 3D, check out the Layer Weight node. (Or volume shading, if that's where you're going). 2D, another issue.. GN+dense mesh, a possibility.